# Significance of quote "I put up pretty pedestrian numbers"

Tags: dialogue, up-in-the-air

In the movie *Up in the Air*, starring George Clooney, there's the following dialogue:

> Alex: I'll say. I put up pretty pedestrian numbers. 60 thousand a year, domestic.
>
> Ryan: That's not bad.
>
> Alex: Don't patronize me. What's your total?
>
> Ryan: It's a personal question.
>
> Alex: Please.
>
> Ryan: And we hardly know each other.
>
> Alex: Come on, show some hubris. Come on, impress me. I bet it's huge.
>
> Ryan: You have no idea.
>
> Alex: How big? What is it, this big? This big?
>
> Ryan: I don't want to brag.
>
> Alex: Oh, come on! Come on.
>
> Ryan: Let's just say I have a number in mind and I haven't hit it yet.

I'm not quite sure what this means. Is it talking about how many people they've slept with or mileage or something else?

Comment: The quote includes "60 thousand a year" and you think it might be "how many people they've slept with"?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

More context here helps.  Here's what precedes this exchange:

> Alex: [going through each others wallets] Oh, my God. I wasn't sure this actually existed. This is the American Airlines...
>
> Ryan: It's a Concierge Key, yeah.
>
> Alex: What is that, carbon fibre?
>
> Ryan: Graphite.
>
> Alex: Oh, I love the weight.
>
> Ryan: I was pretty excited the day that bad boy came in.
>
> Alex: I'll say. I put up pretty pedestrian numbers. 60 thousand a year, domestic.
>
> Ryan: That's not bad.

And here's what follows:

> Ryan: Let's just say I have a number in mind and I haven't hit it yet.
>
> Alex: This is pretty f[***]ing sexy.
>
> Ryan: Hope it doesn't cheapen our relationship.
>
> Alex: We're two people who get turned on by elite status. I think cheap is our starting point.

In context, then: they are talking about their elite status in frequent flyer programs.  Alex & Ryan are both characters who travel a lot for their jobs;  Ryan has been doing this job for many years, and has accrued a super-elite status on some airlines.  Alex is impressed by this.  "Sixty thousand a year, domestic" refers to earning 60,000 miles per year on domestic travel—which would be quite a lot for most people, but is "pedestrian" (i.e., humdrum, unremarkable) by Alex's own standards.